# Facebook API for Android: how to get extended info regarding user`s friends?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I`m working on small Android application, trying to add Facebook support.

Main problem: I can get only basic info regarding user`s friends (id, name).
List of app permissions (offline_access is here just for test, will be removed soon):

```
 String[] sPermissions = { "friends_about_me"
                         , "friends_birthday"
                         , "friends_location"
                         , "friends_website"
                         , "offline_access" };
 mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook,  sPermissions);
```

Following request works fine - returns a list of id:name pairs,

```
 mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new SampleRequestListener());
```

but if I change it in order to get more info

```
 mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,hometown", new SampleRequestListener());
```

server returns error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
I tested these Graph API requests using browser - both of them work as expected.

Small remark: I`m using default debug cetificate to sign apllication and add it hash as facebook application hash according to Facebook instruction:

> Register your application's Android key hash. This is used by Facebook to ensure that another app can't impersonate your app when talking to the Facebook Android app.
>
> Generate the key hash:
>
> keytool -exportcert -alias [alias]
>   -keystore [keystore] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 In the Facebook developer settings, go to the
>   Mobile and Devices tab.
>
> In the Android section, enter the key
>   hash in the Key Hash field.

Maybe there is another way to get user`s frineds info (bday, location, gender and so on)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

`mFacebook.request(graphpath, bundle);`

method,
`Bundle` will have parameters which will be like this

```
graphpath = "me/friends"
bundle.putString("fields","birthday");
```

and call above request method, it will give you birthdays but you have to add `friends_birthday` permission.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `/me/friends` in Graph API all it returns is friends' IDs and names. If you want to get more information about friends you can call `/Friend_ID` afterwards.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion. I tried to call ""me/friends/Friend_ID" - APi returns just list of all friends (id:name).

Comment: First you need to get the IDs so you need to call `/me/friends`. Then you can loop over all friends and for each of them call just `/Friend_ID` (without `me`). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198965/android-get-facebook-friends-who-have-app-downloaded/15196047#15196047) answer in order to know how to get Facebook friend list and who of these friends have installed your app.