# Android: get facebook friends list

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) to post messages on walls.

Now I need to fetch the Facebook friends list.  Can anybody help me with this?

-- Edit --

```
try {

  Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(Constants.FB_APP_ID);
  AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("fields", "birthday");
  mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);

} catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(Constants.LOGTAG, " " + CLASSTAG + " Exception = "+e.getMessage());
}
```

When I execute my `activity`, I'm not seeing anything, but in `LogCat` there is a debug message like:

```
06-04 17:43:13.863: DEBUG/Facebook-Util(409): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?format=json&fields=birthday
```

And when I tried to access this url directly from the browser, I'm getting the following error response:

```
{
  error: {
  type: "OAuthException"
  message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
 }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34354121/3064935 please refer this post to get facebook friend list.

Comment: [please refer this post to get facebook friend list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34354121/3064935)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are about half way there.  You've sent the request, but you haven't defined anything to receive the response with your results.  You can extend `BaseRequestListener` class and implement its `onComplete` method to do that.  Something like this:

```
public class FriendListRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        _error = null;

        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final JSONArray friends = json.getJSONArray("data");

            FacebookActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Do stuff here with your friends array, 
                    // which is an array of JSONObjects.
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            _error = "JSON Error in response";
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            _error = "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        if (_error != null)
        {
            FacebookActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred:  " + 
                                    _error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your request you can specify the request listener to use for receiving the response from the request, like this:

```
mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle, new FriendListRequestListener());
```

Comment: Thank you Kon, but 
mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle, new FriendListRequestListener());
is giving error, so i tried to use "mAsyncRunner" instead of "mFacebook". Error is resolved.
But the Listner metho is still not getting called when i executed my app.
any guesses?

Comment: Hi Kon, can you plz respond...plz

Comment: hey what exactly is the FacebookActivity here ?

Comment: @Kon i want to fetch list of Email addresses of Fb user how can i do it.

Comment: Hey somebody resoved it?
Still, I am getting BaseRequestListener  can not be resolved to a type.

Comment: @ kon : i have got null array .. that means in array no values are in Array .. please help me

Answer (score 5):

Using FQL Query

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
        "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

Request request = new Request(session,"/fql", params,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback(){         
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());

        try{

            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
            Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("uid",friend.getString("uid"));
                Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));
                Log.d("pic_square",friend.getString("pic_square"));             

            }

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }                  
}); 
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: here u put 25 of limit.. that means 25 friends name is displayed of fetched ?

Comment: YES,This will help you for pagination

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with that and I found the answer.
The problem is that you want to access to your data without previous registration with your facebook token.

First, you must to define your Facebook variable:

```
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(getString(R.string.fb_id));
```

Later, define your AsyncFacebookRunner:

```
final AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
```

Ok, now you must to authorize your request, with autorize method. Note that you must implement callback methods on DialogListener(), put attention on onComplete() method. On that method you must to run the friend fetch request. Now your request will pass because now you are authenticated.
Now the code:

```
mFacebook.authorize(this, fb_perms, new DialogListener(){
        /**
         * Triggered on a successful Facebook registration. 
         */
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendListRequestListener());
        }

        /**
         * Triggered on a FacebookError.
         */
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

        }

        /**
         * Triggered on a DialogError.
         */
        public void onError(DialogError e) {

        }

        /**
         * Triggered when the User cancels the Facebook Login.
         */
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    });
```

You can use the FriendListRequestListener class that was post by @Kon

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Defining an instance of a Facebook object is now deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check below link

[Facebook API for Android: how to get extended info regarding user`s friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628822/facebook-api-for-android-how-to-get-extended-info-regarding-users-friends)

[Post on user's friends facebook wall through android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem yesterday.
I wondering if you have overriden the `onActivityResult()` function?

```
private Facebook mFacebook=null;

...
...
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
                                int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this is working good....

```
                    jsonObj = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/friends"));

                    JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.v("THIS IS DATA", i+" : "+jArray.getJSONObject(i));
                     }
```

Hope it is helpful...

Comment: I am getting this warning. Can u suggest me please 08-27 16:28:27.561: W/System.err(1286): com.facebook.android.FacebookError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198965/android-get-facebook-friends-who-have-app-downloaded/15196047#15196047) answer in order to know how to get Facebook friend list and who of these friends have installed your app using new Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is reading this in late 2015, the answer and code is quite simple. Take a look at official documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) (in the code window click on Android SDK). 
Keep in mind that you need to have user_friends permission.

Bro tip for android-rx users - get your friends synchronously, then process message and return Observable:

```
public Observable<List<Friend>> execute() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<List<Friend>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<Friend>> call() {
            AccessToken a = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if (Utils.isValid(a)) {
                try {
                    GraphResponse res = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me/friends").executeAndWait();

                    // process result          

                    return Observable.just(your friend list);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   // notify user or load again
                }
            }
            // invalid access token -> notify user
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```