# android facebook - online friend's list

Tags: android, facebook

In my app, I want to get the on-line Facebook users list of his logged in FB user. I mean, If anyone of his friends come to on-line then he/she will be notified. For this, I am sending one  FQL query to Facebook sever for every 5min and then it return the on-line user list.I mean, I implemented it using polling technique. but I thought it's not good  solution. Is it possible to implement it using Push technology. I mean, Is any solution to get the online user from the FB instead of making requests for every 5 mins.

thanks,
Naresh

Comment: Refer link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236251/android-get-facebook-friends-list

Comment: @ViragBrahme: I want to get the friends list who are in on-line, not the normal friends list. I think, Now it's clear to you?