# Facebook notification click not working on android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app in which user can send invitation to other users to join the app.
Following is my code and notification is being sent perfectly fine:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Join my carpool from " + carpool.source + " to " + carpool.destination);
    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Network Error", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request sent",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Once the notification is send . The invited user clicks on the notification and is shown 
a page in Facebook in which it is written "*Trouble Loading . Tap to retry*"
I have configured the app settings page, but I keep getting this error.

Any insight in this issue will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297850/send-facebook-request-from-android-does-not-show-message-preview-and-does-not-se