# Get My Friend list form Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, android-listview

I am creating an application. I want to access the friends list form Facebook in my app, but i am unable to access the Facebook friends list in my app. All others thinks are accessible, only friend list is not accessible. I have an old app id in which i access all the friends but in my new app id i am unable to access the friend list. In my app, I mention the following permissions:
     1. Public_Profiles
     2. basic_info
     3. user_photos
     4. user friends
     5. read_friendslist

if any others permissions are needed then please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: get facebook friends list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236251/android-get-facebook-friends-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You new app is using API v2.0 and in API v2.0 you can not get all friends. /me/friends will only return friends that are also using the app.

There are some new APIs added in v2.0 that you may be able to use: taggable_friends, invitable_friends and social context.

Comment: with taggable_friends i got id.name.picture. here i am trying to use friend id to get my friend's friend list. but this id is not accessible to get my friend's friends list.

Comment: That is correct. Taggable_friends you use to get friends to tag. Not to get friend's friends list. You can't get friend's friends list

Answer (score 0):

I am getting friends list in two ways:

1. `Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
       if (activeSession.getState().isOpened()) {

   ```
       Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession,
               new GraphUserListCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                           Response response) {

                       UsefullData.Log("Response : " + response.toString());
                       UsefullData.Log("Friends list" + users);
                       //setUserFriendsList(users);
                   }
               });
       Bundle params = new Bundle();
       params.putString("fields", "id, name, picture");
       friendRequest.setParameters(params);
       friendRequest.executeAsync();

   }`
   ```
2. `Request friendRequest = new Request(
               activeSession,
               "/me/friends",
               null,
               HttpMethod.GET,
               new Request.Callback() {
                   public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                       UsefullData.Log("Friends Response : " + response.toString());
                       //setUserFriendsList(response);
                   }
               }
           );friendRequest.executeAsync();`

Note: set custome permission "user_friends" in your session.
both codes are working at my end. I hope it will help for you.