# ANDROID : New app id & secret not fetching facebook friend list

Tags: android

I have implemented **facebook integration app** for android. But when I create new **app id** & **secret id** (creating new app) & pass that app id to

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

It doesn't fetch friend list. But if I keep earlier  `APP_ID`, then I get my friend list. I don't know what is the problem.

Even I have tried these things in browser but I'm getting blank `"data[]{}"`.

Comment: doesn't facebook require your app to be approved by the user? And if you change your ID you would have to repeat that approval process?

Comment: which approval process? I have done same steps those I did while creating app. I have added all neccesssary permissions to

Comment: Here is your answer check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236755/3786760

Comment: Hey buddy, I am able to get friend list but when I create new app id &  pass it to facebook object, it gives me blank friend list data array. Plz read my question carefully